# Difficulties applying texture in 3ds Max for .obj export

Tags: texture, 3ds-max, games, maps

So, I've started creating 3D model for my small application. Im using libgdx. I firstly created a model in 3Ds Max:
[image]

Then, I did this '*render to texture thing*' with those settings: I also used channel 2, like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uc_nW-W1LOA)
[image]

That is what it rendered:
[image]

I checked if everything was ok with the texture, so I applied it as a material bitmap:
[image]
Still, everything looks pretty good here:
[image]

Then I export the model as .obj file:
[image]

Finally, I open fbx-converter, to convert my .obj file to .g3db. And the following shows up:
[image]

So is there any way to fix the texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. I flipped the texture horizontally. Now it looks awesome

- Initial Texture:
  [image]
- Flipped texture:
  [image]
- than I converted my model to .DAE, and it looks awesome:
  [image]

Thanks to @poor and @Xoppa !

ps: It looks awful it 3ds Max now:)